# How to validate a second text box if there is a value in first text box?

Tags: angularjs

I have two text boxes.  If the first contains text, then the second must not be empty.

Can I set up angularJS form validation to cover this use case?

Comment: please be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is an example assuming that both fields are text fields.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input.field1">

<input type="text" ng-model="input.field2" ng-required="angular.isDefined(input.field1) && input.field1.length > 0">
```

Comment: Note that if you enter a value into `field1` then delete it, it'll still be defined (just a blank string), so I would add `&& input.field1.length` to the `ng-required` call to cover this eventuality.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe thanks for pointing that out, updated answer as per your comments

Comment: No probs. P.S. just `&& input.field1.length` is sufficient, as `0` is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

This code example will check if the model of the first input-box is empty, if it is then the second input-box is required.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="first"/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="second" data-ng-required="angular.isDefined(first)"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```